# how to correctly extract separate function

Tags: typescript

```
export const calclulateOrders = (orders: Order[]): Calculations => {
  {
    const groupedOrders = _.groupBy(orders, "order.type");
    return {
      total: orders.length,
      typeOrders: {
        totalCalcOrders: groupedBYType["redOrders"]
          ? groupedBYType["redOrders"].length
          : 0,
      
      },
    };
  }
};
```

How to correctly extract totalCalcOrders to a separate function and call it in calclulateOrders ?
I suppose it might to be something like that :

```
orderTypeBreakDown(orders:Order[]):orderTypeBreakDown
```

Comment: `const getTypeOrders = (orders: Order[]) => groupedByType.redOrders?.length ?? 0;`?

Comment: `totalCalcOrders` is just a shortened `if else` statement. Why do you want to extract it?